# Why does the trigger event not call events defined with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a sample case:

http://jsfiddle.net/y42pu5b6/

```
$(function(){
    function ping (){ 
        alert( "function fired" ); 
        console.log("fired"); 
    }
    console.log($("input#one")[0]);
    $("input#one")[0].addEventListener("change", ping);
    $("input#one").trigger("change");

    $("input#two").on("change", ping);
    $("input#two").trigger("change");

});
```

It seems that with jQuery, you cant "trigger" and event applied with the `addEventListener` call.  Is there a reason for this?  I was under the notion that since trigger is a jquery method, it is only scanning the jQuery object for the handlers, and not what is actually applied to the object.

I feel that trigger should fire for all applicable events, whether they were added via `on` or `addEventListener`.   Maybe it is taking a snapshot of code at timeframe X, and is storing it in the jquery object.  Im not sure.

Maybe someone else has more insight into this than myself?

Comment: @Shomz, You're simply invoking `window.alert()` but do not return any callback function.

Comment: @haim770 Right, totally missed it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since different Browsers handling different events in different ways, jQuery mitigates the problem by introducing its own [Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) abstraction layer (that is also providing [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) among other benefits).

Hence, when you're calling `trigger`, jQuery is only triggering its own-bound events (using `on`, `bind`, `click` etc), but it doesn't try to fire natively-bound events.

See http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess i was just hoping that while there was an abstraction layer for use across the platform, that it could also be used to call existing code.   With this understanding it seems that certain code in older systems, would require design changes, and updated implementations.  i wonder if there is a plugin which would handle "triggering" across platforms.